# How do i make use of .rdlc reports created using the VS 2008 Report Wizard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a c# project where i created a dataset, then when through the steps of creating 3 reports via the Report Wizard. The rdlc files are now in my project and i have a reportviewer control in my Winforms project. The question is, after going through the process of setting up the dataset and reports, how do i get any of them to display in the reportviewer? When i try to set the ReportEmbeddedResource to be one of the rdlc files, i get a message in the viewer saying the source of the data has not been set. I did that when i created the data set and the report.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed tutorial on how to use Local Reports : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252075%28v=vs.90%29

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this last year, Local Reports are kind of a headache. The problem is .rdlc files do not fill their data sets (they ignore all the `<Query` tags. So, what I had to do is write a custom .ascx that would parse the `<Query>` tags in the .rdlc, fill the DataSets, and pass the new file to the ReportViewer control.

Basic steps:
1. Build a set of input fields based on the QueryParameters inside any `<Query>` tags. This usually involved cascading comboboxes since parameters can be dependent.
2. When the user submits the form, fill the DataSet associated with each `<Query>`.

If you look at the way you input parameters in VS 2008 when you test an RDL, the control you will make does exactly that.
All of this had to be done because of a client request to not have to authenticate when running the report...ugh. The fun thing is, I never found a complete schema for RLD/RDLC XML so I had to look at a lot of report files to figure out all the variations.

EDIT: I missed the part where you said WINFORMS. My scenario was for Webforms, though it might still apply I've never used the ReportViewer control in Winforms.